# Symfony2, autoredirect if all parameters are default in route

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Is here any possibility to tell `Symfony2 framework` that if all parameters in my route have default values will be redirected to this same route but withtout them? Same as `Symfony2` generate URL adressses.

For example:

```
default_blog:
    path:     /{type}/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Default:index, type: "page", page: 1}
    requirements:
        page: \d+
        type: page
```

So if i have `/page/2` it will be ok, but if I put `/page/1` to URL I'll be redirected to `/`. Is it possible and if is, how?

Answer (score 0):

In action add parameter `$page` which is a `{page}` placeholder in route and then use `if` for check first page. And same with type:

```
public function pageAction($type, $page) {

    if ($type == 'page' &&  $page == 1) {
        $this->redirect('/');
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not a very nice solution. Then I maybe create redirections in my route. Isn't any global solution for every routes which have all default values?

Comment: It's a nice solution. You can't use redirect direct in routes with check for default values

Comment: But I have to use it manually in my controller. So if I have 10 controllers with 3+ more actions so I have to paste it 30+ times to each action method.

Comment: So why to use a default values?

Comment: The `Controller` responsible for this logic.

Comment: I use default values for generating URL's. But for SEO optimalisation, I can't have 2 different URLs with same content.

Comment: Maybe it can do more easier. Try to read posts about SEO optimization